# Mathematica: Unevaluated vs Defer vs Hold vs HoldForm vs HoldAllComplete vs etc etc

Tags: macros, lisp, language-design, wolfram-mathematica

I'm bewildered by all the built-in Mathematica functions that purport to prevent evaluation in some way: `Unevaluated`, `Defer`, `Hold`, and over half a dozen of the form `Hold*`.  The Mathematica documentation just explains each function in isolation without explaining why you would choose one or the other.  Can anyone offer a coherent explanation of all these functions?  The whole thing seems like a convoluted mess to me.  Relating it all to Lisp macros might be a good place to start.

Most of the Mathematica language is amazingly well-designed but it seems like Wolfram really painted himself into a corner on this aspect.  Or I could be missing something.

Comment: one difference between Hold and HoldForm I immediately see is that the latter doesn't appear when evaluated. For example, `Hold[1+1]` evaluates to itself, but `HoldForm[1+1]` evaluates to `1+1`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are pretty tricky constructs, and it's tough to give clear explanations; they aren't as straightforward as Lisp macros (or, for that matter, the relationship between Lisp's `QUOTE` and `EVAL`). However, there's a good, lengthy discussion available in the form of [notes from  Robby Villegas's 1999 talk "Unevaluated Expressions"](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/377/) on Wolfram's website.

`Defer` is omitted from that talk, because it's new as of Mathematica 6.0. It's a lot like `HoldForm`, except that when it's output in a front-end (but not a bare kernel) it's stripped away, leaving an expression that can be used as input. This is very useful if you want to programmatically construct expressions that a user can edit and evaluate, say in a palette.

Comment: this is technically not an answer and is just a link...