# How to construct a list of Set's

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a large set of parameters P which take several distinct sets of values V_i and want to use `ActionMenu[]` to make assigning P=V_i easy, like so:

```
ActionMenu["Label", {"name_1" :> (P = V_1;),..}]
```

Now the problem is that the set of V_i's is large and not static, so instead of coding a long list `{"opt_1" :> (P = V_1;),..}` over and over by hand, I'd like to generate it.

I am completely stumped at how to do it. The general approach is something like

```
Thread@RuleDelayed[listOfNames,listOfActions]
```

where `listOfActions` should be something like

```
Thread@Set[repeatedListOfP,listOfV_i]
```

But this does not work. And since `Set[]` is a very special function, none of my other usual approaches work (building a `Table[]`, replacing headers, etc). How do you go about constructing a list of `Set[]` operations?

Comment: Could you distill out the ActionMenu part of this, if that's not fundamental to the question?

Comment: Yeah, in the meanwhile I have solved this problem by using SetterBar and Dynamic which is esthetically more pleasing anyway. Still interested in getting a list of Set[] operations though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be more to your question that I haven't grokked yet but maybe this will get you on the right track.

This

```
MapThread[Hold[#1 = #2]&, {{a, b, c}, {1, 2, 3}}]
```

returns a list of unevaluated "Set"s like so:

```
{Hold[a = 1], Hold[b = 2], Hold[c = 3]}
```

If you call ReleaseHold on the above then the assignments will actually happen.

More on Hold and relatives here:
[Mathematica: Unevaluated vs Defer vs Hold vs HoldForm vs HoldAllComplete vs etc etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616592/unevaluated-vs-defer-vs-hold-vs-etc)

Comment: You've hit the nail on the head with "...then the assignments will actually happen". I need Mathematica to give me a literal list of `{(a=1);,(b=2);,...}` without evaluating but also without any Hold[] structures left in there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative solution that I've used when I've wanted to have `RuleDelayed` applications that have side-effects. You use a different head to substitute in for `Set` until you have your expression on the right-hand side of a `RuleDelayed` form (where it'll be held by `RuleDelayed`'s `HoldRest` attribute) and then subsitute `Set` back in. When I do this, I like to use `Module` to create a unique symbol for me. This way you don't have to use `Defer`, which is an even more unpleasantly slippery construct than `Unevaluated`.

Here's an example:

```
Module[{set},
 Attributes[set] = Attributes[Set];

 With[{rhs = MapThread[set, Unevaluated[{{x, y, z}, {1, 2, 3}}]]},
  "name1" :> rhs /. {set -> Set, List -> CompoundExpression}]]
```

The reason the `set` symbol is given the same attributes as `Set`, and the reason the `Unevaluated` is there, is to make sure this works even if someone has already assigned a value to `x`, `y` or `z`.

Another possibility is to wrap all your `Set` expressions up as closures and then use `Scan` to call them when the `RuleDelayed` is evaluated, like so:

```
With[{thunks = MapThread[Function[{a, b}, (a = b) &, HoldAll],
    Unevaluated[{{x, y, z}, {1, 2, 3}}]]},
 "name1" :> Scan[#[] &, thunks]]
```